# Committing hudi files manually

Tags: hive, presto, apache-hudi

I am using spark 3.x with apache-hudi 0.8.0 version.
While I am trying to create presto table by using **hudi-hive-sync** tool I am getting below error.

```
Got runtime exception when hive syncing
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find any data file written for commit [20220116033425__commit__COMPLETED], could not get schema for table
```

But I checked all data for partitiionKeys using zepplin notebook , I see all data present.

Its understood that I need to do manually commit the file. How to do it ?

Comment: hi not sure if this might be of interest https://github.com/apache/hudi/issues/544

Comment: sorry its not of much use.